# Postgres on conflict - insert to another table

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a bulk insert for one table, called `items`.

```
const query = format(`INSERT INTO items (site_id, store_id, title, price, quantity, item_code, package_quantity, unit_adjusted_price) VALUES %L returning id`, items);
```

- I'm using a `format` library that created the bulk insert from an array

It works great, but I want to do two things on conflict:

1. update the `price` field
2. Insert to `price_history` table the new price

Regards #1 - I could find the syntax without any issue, but no idea how to do #2 - insert to a different table on conflict.

Any idea?

Comment: 2) will need to be done with a `TRIGGER` on `items`. See [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) and [plpgsql trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Comment: You should use `trigger` or use `transaction in code` for your section. You can't use in conflict for add or update in another table